# Limit the allowed commands for Redis client

Tags: redis

Is there a way to limit the list of allowed commands in Redis for a certain client identified by login/password? I would want to forbid `KEYS` and `SCAN` commands. Ideally I would allow only `GET` and nothing else, so the client will only be able to access the keys it knows about.

Answer (score 4):

Up to Redis v5, there is no built-in way to do that.

Starting with Redis v6 (ETA soon(TM) ;)) you will be able to use the Access Control List features. In a nutshell, ACL allows the definition of users and their respective permissions in regards to commands they can execute and the keys patterns they can access.

For example, to allow disable everything other than `GET` for the user you could do the following:

```
redis> ACL SETUSER myuser on >password -@all +get
```

The WIP documentation is currently at https://redis.io/topics/acl.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable commands, see: https://redis.io/topics/security

However, this will be applied to all clients.